# Force scatter plot grid to be square in ggpot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I'm trying to force the grid of a scatter plot to be composed of squares, with *x* and *y* values that have different ranges.

I tried to force a square shape of the whole plot (aspect.ratio=1), but this does not solve the problem of different ranges. Then I tried to change limits of values of my axes.

1)Here is what I tried first:

```
p + theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
    coord_fixed(ratio=1, xlim = c(-0.050,0.050),ylim = c(-0.03,0.03))
```

2) I changed the ratio by using the range of the values for each axis:

```
p + coord_fixed(ratio=0.06/0.10, xlim = c(-0.050,0.050), ylim = c(-0.03,0.03))
```

3)Then I changed the limits of *y* to match those of *x*:

```
p + theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
          coord_fixed(ratio=1, xlim = c(-0.050,0.050),ylim = c(-0.05,0.05))
```

1) The grid on the background is composed by rectangles.

[image: Rectangles]

2) I would expect this to change the position of the tick marks automatically in order to give me a grid composed of squares. Still triangles.

[image: still rectangles]

3) It obviously worked 'cause I matched the ranges of *x* and *y*. But there was a lot of empty space in the graph.

[image: Squares but ugly]

Is there something else I should try?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to change the aspect ratio of the plot for this to work?

Comment: Why not just generate an empty plot with a square grid, save it as an image, and apply it as a background to the plot?

Comment: You're missing the code in a couple code blocks

Comment: Thank you. I ended up adapting the ranges of the similarly scaled Y and X axes. Sometimes the graphic will look a bit empty but at least everything is scaled in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the plot to be square and you want the grid to be square you can do this by rescaling the y variable to be on the same scale as the x variable (or vice versa) for plotting, and then inverting the rescaling to generate the correct axis value labels for the rescaled axis.

Here's an example using the `mtcars` data frame, and we'll use the `rescale` function from the `scales` package.

First let's create a plot of `mpg` vs. `hp` but with the `hp` values rescaled to be on the same scale as `mpg`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
theme_set(theme_bw())

p = mtcars %>% 
  mutate(hp.scaled = rescale(hp, to=range(mpg))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, hp.scaled)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_fixed() +
  labs(x="mpg", y="hp")
```

[image]

Now we can invert the rescaling to generate the correct value labels for `hp`. We do that below by supplying the inverting function to the `labels` argument of `scale_y_continuous`:

```
p + scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) rescale(x, to=range(mtcars$hp)))
```

[image]

But note that rescaling back to the original `hp` scale results in non-pretty breaks. We can fix that by generating pretty breaks on the `hp` scale, rescaling those to the `mpg` scale to get the locations where we want the tick marks and then inverting that to get the label values. However, in that case we won't get a square grid if we want to keep the overall plot panel square:

```
p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = rescale(pretty_breaks(n=5)(mtcars$hp), 
                                        from=range(mtcars$hp), 
                                        to=range(mtcars$mpg)),
                       labels = function(x) rescale(x, from=range(mtcars$mpg), to=range(mtcars$hp)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what code you are using, it is missing in block 1 and 3. But using the mtcars data set the following works:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
  geom_point() +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(10, 35, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 6, 1))
```

The last two lines make it clear that 1 point on the x-axis is equal to 1 point on the y-axis.

In the documention you will further find the following advise:

> ensures that the ranges of axes are equal to the specified ratio by
>   adjusting the plot aspect ratio